# Java casting in interfaces

Tags: java, interface, casting

Can someone please explain to me how the compiler does not complain in the first casting, but does complain in the second?

```
interface I1 { }
interface I2 { }
class C1 implements I1 { }
class C2 implements I2 { }

public class Test{
     public static void main(String[] args){
        C1 o1 = new C1();
        C2 o2 = new C2();
        Integer o3 = new Integer(4);

        I2 x = (I2)o1; //compiler does not complain
        I2 y = (I2)o3; //compiler complains here !!
     }
}
```

Comment: By running this, you will encounter `ClassCastException`, which is a `RuntimeException`.

Comment: @BuhakeSindi you are wrong

Comment: @BuhakeSindi The OP said that the compiler complained suggesting to me that you do not get a chance to run this.

Comment: @emory, even if he could get it to compile by fixing the item that had a compiler error, the line above it would have caused a `ClassCastException`.

Comment: @BuhakeSindi You are wrong because you speak the things that you should not. The water is wet. But it is wrong to speak about this issue in this context. Ok? Obviously, the questioner know about it because he does an experiment.

Comment: The reason i asked was because i could not understand why the compiler behaves differently in these two cases. Now it makes sense. Thanks!!

Comment: @Val, the water is wet doesn't make sense. The water is liquid does. It may seem obvious for many but we can't just assume that it's obvious for everyone. Rather, let's bring out the obvious for clarification instead of letting it slide.

Answer (score 152, accepted):

When you cast `o1` and `o3` with `(I2)`, you tell the compiler that the class of the object is actually a subclass of its declared type, and that this subclass implements `I2`.

The `Integer` class is **final**, so `o3` cannot be an instance of a subclass of `Integer`: the compiler knows that you're lying. `C1` however is not final, so `o1` *could* be an instance of a subtype of `C1` that implements `I2`.

If you make `C1` final, the compiler will complain too:

```
interface I1 { }
interface I2 { }
final class C1 implements I1 { }
class C2 implements I2 { }

public class Test{
     public static void main(){
        C1 o1 = new C1();
        C2 o2 = new C2();
        Integer o3 = new Integer(4);

        I2 y = (I2)o3; //compiler complains here !!
        I2 x = (I2)o1; //compiler complains too
     }
}
```

Comment: "Integer is final, so o3 as no chance of being of interface I2" That's pretty much wrong in this form. Not the meaning, but the phrasing.

Comment: @WilQu I wasn't complaining about the typo, but the phrasing of the answer. If you take a look below, you'll see how much clearer Etienne's phrasing of the same thing is. Yours can be misunderstandable, thus misleading as you didn't mention (for example) that **the class** of `Integer` is final (which is obvious to me and you but probably not to everyone) and the *"has no chance of being an interface"* part does not carry too much information; in fact the info in question is hidden in the second sentence. One might even think that `final` classes can't implement inferfaces which is not true.

Comment: @Powerslave thanks for your comments, I edited my answer again. I tried to add more explanation, I hope it does not make my answer even more confusing.

Comment: @WilQu Excellent! Turned out to be a very nice explanation :)

Answer (score 37):

According to [JLS chapter 5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.5)

#### 5.5.1. Reference Type Casting

> Given a compile-time reference type S (source) and a compile-time reference type T (target), a casting conversion exists from S to T if no compile-time errors occur due to the following rules.
> If T is an interface type:
>
> If S is not a final class (§8.1.1), then, if there exists a supertype X of T, and a supertype Y of S, such that both X and Y are provably distinct parameterized types, and that the erasures of X and Y are the same, a compile-time error occurs.
>
> Otherwise, the cast is always legal at compile time (because even if S does not implement T, a subclass of S might).
>
> If S is a final class (§8.1.1), then S must implement T, or a compile-time error occurs.

Answer (score 25):

That's because class `Integer` is final and `C1` is not. Thus, an Integer object cannot implement I2, while a C1 object could if it is an instance of a subclass of C1 that implements I2.

Answer (score 15):

According to [JLS 5.5.1 - Reference Type casting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.5.1), the rule(s) apply:

- **If T is a class type, then either |S| <: |T|, or |T| <: |S|. Otherwise, a compile-time error occurs.**

  `I2 y = (I2)o3; //compiler complains here !!`

In this case, an `Integer` and `I2` are **unrelated** in any way, so a compile-time error occurs. Also, because `Integer` is `final`, there is no relation between `Integer` and `I2`.

`I2` and `I1` can be related due to both being a marker interface (there are no contract).

As for the compiled code, the rule follows:

- **If S is not a final class (§8.1.1), then, if there exists a supertype X of T, and a supertype Y of S, such that both X and Y are provably distinct parameterized types, and that the erasures of X and Y are the same, a compile-time error occurs.**

`S` is `o1` and `T` is `I2`.

Hope this helps.